# Transformar .py a exe sin consola despues de programa

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

Quiero transformar un archivo .py, con una interfaz grafica
Al transformarlo al exe sale bien, pero al abrir el exe se me abre una consola de comandos seguido del programa

**¿como elimino esa consola de comandos y solo quede el programa en si?.**

*ayuda por favor*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tenias que especificar una configuración extra al transformarlo, no recuerdo cual era, voy a investigar y te lo digo

Comment: estas usando pyintaller? o que utilizas?

Comment: Suponiendo que usas Pyinstaller, cuando conviertes el py en exe tienes que especificarle el parametro -w.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los pasos serian los siguientes:

1. Intalación (PyInstaller)

> pip install pyinstaller

2. Crear el archivo distribuido del ejectutable:

> pyinstaller archivo.py

Opcionalmente podemos tener del segundo punto:

- **Desaparecer terminal de fondo (opcional)**. Para que desaparezca
  tenemos que indicar que es una aplicación en ventana, y eso lo
  hacemos de la siguiente forma al crear el ejecutable.

> pyinstaller --windowed archivo.py

- **Ejecutable en un solo fichero (opcional)**. Por defecto Pyinstaller crea un directorio con un montón de ficheros. Podemos utilizar un comando para generar un solo fichero ejecutable que lo contenga todo, solo considera que este ocupara bastante más:

> pyinstaller --windowed --onefile archivo.py

- **Cambiar el icono (opcional)**. También podemos cambiar el icono por defecto del ejecutable. Para ello necesitamos una imagen en formato .ico en el mismo directorio donde tenemos el script.

> pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=./hola.ico archivo.py

Espero te sea de ayuda.

¡Saludos!