# ¿Como se puede ocultar la consola o Interprete de Python?

Tags: python, terminal

Necesito que al momento de ejecutar mi pequeña aplicación que es una Calculadora Básica con una interfaz gráfica de Tkinter de Python, se oculte el interprete de Python que muestra en la terminal CMD de Windows, ya que quisiera que al ejecutarse unicamente el ejecutable, solo se muestre como tal y no haya otras ventanas distrayendo al usuario cuando lo utilice, esto me ayudaría bastante para su posterior presentación.

Agradezco su ayuda colegas.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Calculadora - AllanGer6")
ventana.geometry("300x400")
```

Indice de caracteres ingresados en el eTexto

```
i = 0
```

Entrada

```
eTexto = tkinter.Entry(ventana, font="Calibri 20")
eTexto.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=5)
```

Funciones

```
def clickBoton(valor):
    global i
    eTexto.insert(i, valor)
    i += 1
    return


def borrar():
    global i
    eTexto.delete(0, END)
    i = 0

    return


def operacion():
    ecuacion = eTexto.get()
    resultado = eval(ecuacion)
    eTexto.delete(0, END)
    eTexto.insert(0, resultado)
    i = 0
    return
```

Botones

```
boton1 = Button(ventana, text="1", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(1))
boton2 = Button(ventana, text="2", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(2))
boton3 = Button(ventana, text="3", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(3))
boton4 = Button(ventana, text="4", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(4))
boton5 = Button(ventana, text="5", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(5))
boton6 = Button(ventana, text="6", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(6))
boton7 = Button(ventana, text="7", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(7))
boton8 = Button(ventana, text="8", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(8))
boton9 = Button(ventana, text="9", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(9))
boton0 = Button(ventana, text="0", width=13, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(0))

botonBorrar = Button(ventana, text="AC", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: borrar())
botonParentesis1 = Button(ventana, text="(", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton(" 
("))
botonParentesis2 = Button(ventana, text=")", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: 
clickBoton(")"))
botonPunto = Button(ventana, text=".", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton("."))

botonDiv = Button(ventana, text="/", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton("/"))
botonMult = Button(ventana, text="x", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton("*"))
botonSum = Button(ventana, text="+", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton("+"))
botonRest = Button(ventana, text="-", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: clickBoton("-"))
botonIgual = Button(ventana, text="=", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: operacion())
```

Agregar los botones

```
botonBorrar.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
botonParentesis1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
botonParentesis2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
botonDiv.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

boton7.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
boton8.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
boton9.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
botonMult.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

boton4.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
boton5.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
boton6.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
botonSum.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

boton1.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
boton2.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
boton3.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
botonRest.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

boton0.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
botonPunto.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
botonIgual.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Creo recordar que si nombras el archivo como `.pyw` en vez de `.py`, al hacer doble click sobre él no se muestra la consola. Si estás usando `python.exe` desde algún otro programa para lanzar tu script, cámbialo por `pythonw.exe`

Comment: ¿Se puede decir que tu pregunta es prácticamente un duplicado de [esta otra](/q/461919/transformar-py-a-exe-sin-consola-despues-de-programa)? (Aunque no hacés referencia a pyinstaller).

Comment: Me ganaste por la mano... efectívamente, si renombras el archivo, solo se abre el GUI, sin mostrar la consola de python.

Comment: Gracias Colegas! Funcionó cambiando la extensión de .py a .pyw, ahora podré entregarlo mucho más estético.

Comment: me gustaría saber un poco más de como solucionaste. Este cambio .py a .pyw , donde lo realizaste? es decir a qué archivo y si lo hiciste en la carpeta donde ya se encuentra el ejecutable. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo podes hacer con pyinstaller. A su vez te permite convertirlo en .exe:
[Transformar .py a exe sin consola despues de programa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/461919/transformar-py-a-exe-sin-consola-despues-de-programa)

Comment: Si bien el enlace puede ser de ayuda se recomienda agregar el código para que tanto el autor de la pregunta como otros usuarios puedan probar la solución y verificarla leyendo el código. Por favor lee [answer]